# Prevent unwanted logs in heroku

Tags: logging, heroku-postgres, papertrail-app

I have successfully deployed a production-level app in heroku. Now I'm working on logging and monitoring.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to control what is being logged in heroku logs, papertrail, etc. Every 1 or 2 minutes, I get the following kind of messages:

```
app/heroku-postgres source=DATABASE addon=postgresql-slippery-76303 
sample#current_transaction=1408 sample#db_size=11563679bytes 
sample#tables=24 sample#active-connections=13 sample#waiting- 
connections=0 sample#index-cache-hit-rate=0.99834 sample#table-cache- 
hit-rate=0.99896 sample#load-avg-1m=0.01 sample#load-avg-5m=0.005 
sample#load-avg-15m=0 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.098361 
sample#tmp-disk-used=33849344 sample#tmp-disk-available=72944943104 
sample#memory-total=4044932kB sample#memory-free=1741488kB 
sample#memory-cached=1968548kB sample#memory-postgres=44600kB
```

I found out the documentation page from heroku about that:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-metrics-logs

They forgot to tell, though, how can I disable these postgres metrics logs.

In general, I would like to filter what get's logged, because heroku has a limit of logged lines and I wanted to log only what is useful for me. So, if I wanted to disable all logs coming from a specific program, like app/heroku-postgres, I would like to have the option to do so.

Is it there a way in heroku to configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These log lines are not configurable from Heroku's side. Presumably, that's because this is one of the few ways you're able to observe the health of your database host. Heroku maintains a minimal log buffer for you and instead expect that you'll configure your own logging addon, many are free. It's possible that some of these same addons could potentially filter/drop on regex. That being said, it's probably not wise to drop those log lines if you care at all about monitoring your database.

Comment: I think there are better ways to monitore the database than logging a bunch of values in papertrail every 2 minutes. I get that receiving the logs is not configurable from heroku logs's side. But what about heroku-postgres? I should be able to configure whether it prints metrics at all, or at least the interval between successive prints. The way it is right now, I will always filter out what's coming from heroku-postgres, and possibly lose some warning about a long query for example.

Comment: The database host will emit that metric log line and send it to your application logs, period. There's no way to stop it from being sent. Your only option is to filter them out with your logging addon. For the record, these "bunch of values" are the only place you have access to the load average of your database host, IO numbers, and OS page cache information.

Comment: Even if it is the only way, I would expect to be able to change at least the frequency of logging. I won't actually check the load average of my database host every minute of every day! It is sad if the postgres heroku add-on is really such an unhackable black box.